# MassTransit Saga delayed exchange error

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm configuring the massTransit buss with RabbitMq to use the delayed exchange plugin:

`sbc.UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler();`

I'm using schedule events in a saga, everything is working fine but I'm getting the following error:

> RabbitMQ delayed exchange does not support cancellation

Does anything special needs to be configured?

Answer (score 0):

This is it, there is nothing to configure.

Delayed exchange does not support unscheduling so if you use request/response with timeouts or regular unschedule - it will not work.

Comment: I wonder if I should just silently fail, versus throwing an exception, so this doesn't happen.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I think it is important that people know when messages aren't being unscheduled. MT also fails in sagas requesr-response when there is no scheduling configured.

Comment: Hi, the message is correctly scheduled on my end but the exception is thrown and does not affect the behavior of the saga, don't know if that helps

Comment: The issue is that when you will decide to Unschedule, it will not work. May be Chris is right and MT needs to give a warning and only throw on Unschedule.

Comment: Agreed, a warning should be sufficient, as this is the current behavior of rabbitmq. Then the client is aware and needs to handle unscheduling with a different mechanism.